# How do I divide my total money into small sums for different purposes?

Tags: banking

I was wondering if any bank/app has a user interface where I can virtually divide my total money into sub-accounts. For example, if I have 10000 USD, then 2000 USD for travel, 500 USD medical, and the money available to a debit card is the leftover money. I just wanted this feature for the peace of mind and in the background, all the money can be into a single savings account.

Comment: If all you need to do is manually keep track of your balances, then a spreadsheet will do the trick just fine.  For example, Google Sheets so that you have it on your phone and laptop/desktop.

Comment: Many banks allow you to create a budget and track it through their online services. There are also plenty of budgeting apps that allow you to link a bank account. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: GNU Cash lets you create subaccounts for this exact purpose. My single savings account is represented in GNU Cash by an account with multiple special-purpose subaccounts. Money for future house repairs goes into one sub account, money for my emergency fund goes into another (with some of *that* getting rolled into a CD as parts of my ladder mature0, money for vacation in to a third, etc. If I withdraw money to pay for, say, a new roof, I withdraw from savings and deduct it from the house maintenance sub account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many banks allow for multiple savings accounts, for example with Capital One I can have up to 25 savings accounts. However, rather than dividing your banking into multiple accounts a proper budget that accounts for these buckets will be a much more valuable tool over the long-term.

I recommend zero-based budgets in which you plan for how every dollar will be spent rather than having a pile of 'extra'. It's not as rigid as it sounds, it just means you plan ahead for all spending and can adjust as needed. There are plenty of spreadsheet templates and budget application that support zero-based budgets.